# How to export to BibTeX in Journal of Biomechanics?

Tags: citing, bibtex

The citation export format that the digital library of the [Journal of Biomechanics](http://www.jbiomech.com/) is End-note by default. Is there any way that this can be exported in BibTeX?

Comment: Converters from RIS to bibtex might be helpful in case there is no such option, for example see http://www.bruot.org/ris2bib/

Comment: is this question really related to academia?

Comment: biber can work with RIS files.

Comment: I fail to see that this question is on topic. If the question would be *how can i convert RIS to BibTeX* sure, but this is like asking for *my supermarket just sells apples. How can i make them sell oranges*

Answer (score 3):

Use the DOI API, it works out of the box from the terminal in Linux and Mac, and it is probably possible to do from Windows too:

```
curl -LH "Accept: text/bibliography; style=bibtex" http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jbiomech.2015.10.038
```

Note that the DOI sometimes is missing some values, and won't escape capitalised words (proper names, acronyms... should be in curly braces like so: `{PDB}`, `{Einstein}'s equations`).

Answer (score 2):

`biber` can hndle RIS files, but the support is still experimental. Had to change the title tag in order to make it work, which tells us:
*Do not rely on citations exported by a website. Always do a sanity check.*

[image: risTestBiber]

```
%\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.ris}

TY  - JOUR
ID  - testentry
TI  - Experimental Identification of Potential Falls in Older Adult Hospital Patients
AU  - Cloutier, Aimee
AU  - Yang, James
AU  - Pati, Debajyoti
AU  - Valipoor, Shabboo
N1  - doi: 10.1016/j.jbiomech.2016.02.012
DO  - 10.1016/j.jbiomech.2016.02.012
T2  - Journal of Biomechanics
JF  - Journal of Biomechanics
PB  - Elsevier
SN  - 0021-9290
M3  - doi: 10.1016/j.jbiomech.2016.02.012
UR  - http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jbiomech.2016.02.012
Y2  - 2016/02/17
ER  - 
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[maxbibnames=5]{biblatex}
\addbibresource[datatype=ris]{\jobname.ris}
\begin{document}
\citeauthor{testentry} wrote \citetitle{testentry} in
\citeyear{testentry}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just checked with Biber 2.3. I also get four `Use of uninitialized value $last_tag in hash element at` errors, but still everything looks fine ...

Comment: @moewe I can't recall any warning. But with 2.4 it ends up  with `I didn't find a database entry for 'testentry' (section 0)`.

Comment: Didn't you mention this warning/error [comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298043/how-to-make-bibtex-customa-entries-look-exactly-like-article/298080?noredirect=1#comment721652_298080)? The rest seems to be working for me. (Except the DOI isn't recognised even though according to Wikipedia this is OK).

Comment: @moewe I can't recall a warning when writing the answer. I checked today because endnote and zotero support is dropped with 3.4 and 2.4, so i checked this answer here. Biber reports the uninitialized value thing 20 times followed by `didn't find a database entry`. So, this is localized to my machine?

Comment: The screenshot shows the DOI.

Comment: It might not be localised to your machine, I am running MikTeX and so I'm not using Biber 2.4 yet. I don't think RIS support is supposed to be dropped, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The screen shot shows the DOI, but it is not actually the DOI field (`DO`), it is the note field (`N1`). You can tell by the fact that "doi" is not in small caps as usually in standard `biblatex`.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I didn't pay attention. Should have listen to the italic part of the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your BibTeX database is a critical resource. As such, what you can get from external sources can be taken only as a first, rough draft (for instance, the BibTeX entries from the ACM journals suck heavily: wrong capitalization, missing/redundant/useless fields, ...). You should invest the time to check them for accuracy, fix mistakes, and complete *all* relevant fields. In the end, you'll have to do it only once.

In a series of projects I guided we set up a central BibTeX database, which everybody could add to and fix, used by all our papers and theses. That guaranteed complete, correct citations, and cut down on duplicate work.

Answer (score -1):

Search for the title in Google scholar. Then export to bibtex.