# How to make bibtex CUSTOMA entries look exactly like ARTICLE?

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have one entry in my bibfile which I made of type CUSTOMA (it could be any of customa to customf). I did this so that it does not show in the reference list  created with `\printbibliography[nottype=customa]`.

The whole bibliography is generated from:

```
\RequirePackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=apa,
]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
```

Later, I want to display this only entry with

`printbibliography[type=customa]`

It is always to be formatted as an article. Hence, my question: is it possible to define the style of CUSTOMA to be identical to the style of ARTICLE in a reference list?

I thought that

`\DeclareBibliographyAlias{customA}{article}`

would do the trick but the journal's name, the pages and volume do not show up...

Comment: Please give us a complete, compilable and short code including three entries of your bibfile showing one usual entry and two custom? entrys.

Comment: I strongly suspect this is an instance of the XY problem. If an entry should look like an `@article`, it probably *is* and `@article`. You can filter certain works using other methods than type filtering: keywords, categories etc. So you might want to rethink your approach here.

Comment: @moewe I could bet all `customa` entries are own publications which are printed in a sepatate list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, but because how `\DeclareBibliographyAlias` is implemented internally (you can read more about that in [What exactly is the relationship Biblatex refers to as an alias of an entry type? And how should the formatting of aliased entry types be configured?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/268553/35864)), you must give all entry types in lower case.

So the correct line is

```
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{customa}{article}
```

To make sure *everything* is as with `@article` you also need

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[customa]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[customa]{volume}{#1}% volume of a journal
```

for the standard styles and

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[customa]{title}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[customa]{origtitle}{\MakeSentenceCase*{#1}\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[customa]{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[customa]{volume}{\mkbibemph{\apanum{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[customa]{number}{\mkbibparens{\apanum{#1}}}
```

with `biblatex-apa`. The reasons for this are explained in the link above.

Comment: Why aren't you never in our chat room? :-) Can you check on [How to export to BibTeX in Journal of Biomechanics?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/294393), please? `biber` is giving me `Use of uninitialized value $last_tag in hash element`

Comment: @Johannes_B I would probably get even less work done if I was.

Comment: @DenisCousineau Great! But please consider my comment below the question. I think you could make your life a bit easier if you used a different approach.